# How to calculate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n(1- \sqrt[n]{n}) = \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> > **Problem**
> >     Show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n(1- \sqrt[n]{n}) = \infty$ by the following consequence.
> >
> > Consider the sequence $(s_n)$ defined by $s_n=1 + 1/2 + \cdots + 1/n$.
> >
> > (a) $n(n+1)^{1/n} < n+ s_n $ , for all integers $n >1$ ;
> >
> > (b) $(n-1)n^{-1/(n-1)} < n-s_n $, for all integers $n>2$.

I know how to prove the above inequality, but I don't know how to show $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n(1- \sqrt[n]{n}) = \infty$.

Also, is there any other ways to prove the limit?

Comment: "Also, is there any other ways to prove the limit?" Definitely, and with a one-line proof requiring no cleverness whatsoever: $\sqrt[n]{n}=\exp((\ln n)/n)=1+(\ln n)/n+O((\ln n)^2/n^2)$ hence $n(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)\sim\ln n\to+\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

This follows from the basic limit
$$\lim\limits_{y \to 0}\frac{\ln(1+y)}{y}=1$$

if we let $y=\sqrt[n]{n}-1$ then we have

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln n}{n(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)}=1$$

Your limit is therefore $-\infty$.

Comment: Simple and beautiful +1